# QGIS Graphic Modeler issues with Raster Calculator

Tags: qgis

A colleague and I have downloaded QGIS Dufour and are trying to use the Graphical Modeler to carry out a raster subtraction with a DSM and a DTM. This fails using both the Grid Difference and Raster Calculator tools with a message box saying the output file could not be opened.

If the same operation is attempted using the Raster Calculator outside of the Graphical Modeler it works fine and a good result is achieved.

Has anyone got any ideas or a solution?

Thanks,

Ed

Comment: Hi, can you paste the content of the message box. Thank you.

Comment: What does the log say from menu Processing > History and log.
What type of installation did you use: Standalone / OSGeo4W / Linux / Mac

Comment: Another log: C:\Users\MYUSER\.qgis2\processing\processing_qgis.log

Comment: Grid system: 1; 1000x 1000y; 0.5x 0.5y
Grids: 2 objects (2mresdsm, 2mresdtm))
Grids from different Systems: No objects
Result: Result
Formula: dsm - dtm
Name: Calculation
Take Formula: no
Use NoData: no


error: Error in formula at position 0
[d] sm - dtm
function not found


error: executing module [Grid Calculator]

Comment: I think I'm making a newbie error. The formula seems to have an error and fails to work which has a knock on effect. Having named the raster inputs dsm and dtm I am entering dsm - dtm into the raster calculator equation box. Is there a syntax issue?

Comment: Installation - Standalone Windows

Comment: PS Underdark, why the edits? Now a problem just a querie...

Comment: I can reproduce your error. Grid difference works in QGIS Raster Calcualtor, but not in Processing Framework. Both Graphical modeler and a native call to SAGA returns a error. Se below:

Comment: Oooops! The following output layers could not be open
Difference (A - B): C:\Users\JAL\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\e0b28c53264e4c79bb5fc487a2ba6ba0\C.tif
The above files could not be opened, which probably indicates that they were not correctly produced by the executed algorithm
Checking the log information might help you see why those layers were not created as expected
This algorithm requires SAGA to be run. A test to check if SAGA is correctly installed and configured in your system has been performed, with the following result:
SAGA seems to be correctly installed and configured

Comment: Hi Jake, Thanks for your efforts. Both Grass and Saga are installed, open and I have assumed that both are used in the background of QGIS rather than me having everything open at the same time. Have you managed to find a solution? Ed